# How to remove unwanted indent from HAML's pre tag

Tags: haml

I have problem with `<pre>`, here is my code, and the screenshot is attached below. How to remove the indents?

```
%pre.code
    :escaped
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" name="empID" />
                    <input type="submit"/>      
                </form> 
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to use the `#preserve` helper to convert the newlines in the `pre` to newline entities, like so:

```
%pre.code
    = preserve do
        :escaped
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="empID" />
                        <input type="submit"/>        
                    </form>   
                </body>
            </html>
```

In the future, you'll be able to nest filters, so you can do `:preserve:escaped`.

Comment: `:preserve` won't escape your content, and `:escaped` won't preserve it. That's why you need the nested filters.

Comment: I ran into this same issue, but I had to use "= preserve do", not "- preserve do", could be a version issue.

Comment: Used `= preserve` in couple with `%div{ style:"white-space: pre-wrap" }<= text`, nice.

Answer (score 2):

When representing "pre" like text from a variable inside a div or other tag, use

```
.text.plain= preserve(@mail.body.to_s)
```

along with CSS "white-space: pre-wrap;". Use the one-line version, because the two-line will still indent the first line.

```
/ BAD: Will leave the first line incorrectly indented!
.text.plain
  = preserve(@mail.body.to_s)
```