# Create code with content_tag without indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to insert a code snippet into my page using the `content_tag` function. Below is a sample of my code

```
src_code = 'my code ...'
content_tag :pre do
  content_tag :code do
    src_code
  end
end
```

Where the `src_code` variable is storing this string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  do some stuff...
}
```

After running, this code outputs the following markup:

```
<pre><code>#include <stdio.h>
  int main(void) {
    do some stuff...
  }
</code></pre>
```

The problem is that the second line right after the opening tags has an extra level of indentation. The original code snippet only has one tab indent inside of the main function.

This is what I see in my browser:

```
#include <stdio.h>
  int main(void) {
    do some stuff...
  }
```

Everything, except for the first line, has an extra level of indentation. How can I stop the `content_tag` function from adding that extra indentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and testing I finally figured out the problem. The issue was not how `include_tag` was generating the markup, it was working just fine. The problem was when Haml rendered the rest of the page it was adding extra tabs to the markup. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993993/how-to-remove-unwanted-intend-from-hamls-pre-tag) then helped resolve my issue. by simply calling `preserve` before rendering my content the spacing and new lines where kept intact.